# value representation in graphs with javascript's replace function

Tags: javascript, replace

Is it possible to represent/convert/transform any value within a HTML-document into (any) graph with JavaScript's replace function.

For example, when I have the given value "3 ghz" within my HTML-document, I want it to be replaced by (for example) a progress bar that puts the value "3" within a progress bar, which the progress bar, represents numbers from 0 to 5, so that you have a visual representation of the number 3, to give a visual feedback of the given value "3 ghz".

Just want to know if its possible, and if there is anything like it.

Thanks in advance,
Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do such things. The main problem is to distinguish the command from the contents of the page. First, use command names that are better distinguishable, if you can (e.g. "my_progress_bar(3)" instead of "3 ghz". It is even better if the info is somewhere not visible to the user, not directly in the content: `<span class="my_progress_bar_3"></span>`. If you must use the contents for some reason then try marking it with something that does not alter the page: `<span class="dont_change_formating command">3 ghz</span>`. If even this is not an option and you really have to find "3 ghz" in the text content "some words 1 2 3 ghz kql bsk" then you must either be sure that "3 ghz" is not included in the content for any other reason than your progressbar or you'll have to mark other usages somehow or live with those also being replaced.